# Secondary DNS not resolving for client

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm learning about DNS and set up a lab. Hopefully I can explain this. So, I set up an AD-Integrated zone on Server1 and a Secondary zone on Server2. I added Computer1 (DNS pointed to Server2), works great. Added Laptop1 (DNS pointed to Server2), works great. The issue is when I try resolving using Server2 when it hasn't been updated yet. **So my question is, Will the Secondary DNS server not ask the Primary for new records if a client asks for an unknown host?** From the secondary I can resolve from the Primary and it will update its zone, then I can resolve from a client computer. I have the forwarder configured and recursion is enabled. What am I missing. Sorry if I don't paint a clear picture, let me know if you have any questions and thank you in advanced.

-Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're mixing up your zone types. If both servers are Domain Controllers and DNS servers for AD then you don't need a Secondary zone on server 2. AD integrated zones will replicate between the two DC/DNS servers.

Remove the Secondary zone on server 2 and allow AD to replicate the zone from server 1 to server 2.

**EDIT**

Based on your response to my comment I'd suggest that you either exclusively use AD integrated zones or exclusively use standard Primary/Secondary zones, but not the two together. While it is possible, it's fairly unorthodox and you're not likely to see that in the "real world", not to mention it probably isn't the best method of learning Windows DNS.

Use one type exclusively and learn that. Then use the other type exclusively and learn that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, Server 2 is domain joined but not a domain controller. I figured it is easier and better to use AD integrated but I'm trying to learn and understand DNS better. Thank you for your quick response.